# Adding existing functions in TypeScript: Node.getAttribute()

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

What is the best way to add a function to typescript that actually exists already? In my case this is `Node.getAttribute()`, which is actually built-in to the browser, but not yet recognized by TypeScript. It errors: `Cannot find property 'getAttribute' on type 'Node'.`

In my case I ran into this error executing the following:

```
var xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"),
    rootfile    = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("aNode")[0];

console.log(rootfile.getAttribute("anAttribute"));
```

This succeeds in the browser, but throws an error by TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interfaces are open ended just tell typescript about it:

```
interface Node {
    getAttribute(attr: string): string;
}
```

I recommend doing this in a `globals.d.ts` file at the root of your project.

Comment: I will try this, but when I'm modifying *lib.d.ts* with the same instructions nothing happens...

Comment: The `lib.d.ts` that you are modifying is not necessarily the one used by your Dev Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change your code to the following it should all just work.

```
rootfile = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("aNode")[0] as HTMLElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the d.ts files for Node at definitely typed https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped
That would be easier than rewriting the whole node definitions by hand...