# Puppeteer / Typescript: How can I cast to Element in a eval$ page function?

Tags: typescript, element, puppeteer, getattribute

I try to read the value of an attribute in puppeteer:

```
const value = attribute && await page.$eval(selector, (node: Element, name: string) => {
    return node.getAttribute(name)
}, attribute.name);
```

which results in

> error TS2339: Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'Element'.

When I cast

> node: any

instead of node: Element, it works fine.

The reason for this seems to be that React overloads the type as

> interface Element { }

in node_modules/@types/react/gloabal.d.ts

How can I cast to the standard Element?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999416/typescript-puppeteer-library-error-cannot-find-name-element or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429520/adding-existing-functions-in-typescript-node-getattribute

Comment: Yes, thanks! Adding dom to lib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Puppeteer library error: "Cannot find name 'Element'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999416/typescript-puppeteer-library-error-cannot-find-name-element)

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, it was generated by StackOverflow. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing the `dom` lib from your `tsconfig.json`. Add it as follows:

```
"lib": [
    "dom",
    "es2018"
],
```

If adding the lib doesn't help, try declaring the needed method explicitly with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```js
interface Element {
    getAttribute(name: string): string;
}
```

With that you can extend arbitrary type as you like.